# Isolate data between users in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've created an blazor server side app with individual account authentication. To see the content of the app user needs to be logged in.
Let say I have a page where user can create a list of ToDo's (CRUD). So I will have page where user can Add a To Do item and a buttons to edit  the Item. ToDo Items will have a FK with UserId, in order to display in the page only the elements to that specific user.
The edit page of the ToDoItem will have the following route:

```
@page "/ToDoPage/{ToDoItemId}"
```

So, when user1 enter in the ToDo page only their ToDoItems will be display. But, in the edit page, if user2 is accesing "domain.com/ToDoPage/id" it will be able to see and modify the item of user1, which is not the desired behavior.

The question is, how can i use authorizing or other mechanism in order to prevent user 2 to access the items of user one in edit page.

Comment: You know which user is accessing and you have a relation from Auth user to app user ID, right? Then you have all you need to filter.

Comment: Yes, I Have. The point is, if user 2 is navigating to the following Page domain.com/ToDoPage/3, where "3" is the page where u can edit an Item, and "3" is also the id of in item created by the user 1, no one is stopping the user 2 to access that page. It's not about the ToDo List Itself, yes this is filtered, it's about the edit page.

Comment: You cannot have conflicting routes, of course. Nothing is stopping anyone to call a certain uri. _You_ need to keep them from having success. Just because a user is authenticated in your app, it doesn't mean he is authorized for every resource in your api.